# Inverse validity error in rails when importing records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, inverse-relationship

I'm getting the error `ActiveRecord::InverseOfAssociationNotFoundError (Could not find the inverse association for sponsorships (:sponsor_type in LegiscanModel::Sponsorship)` when importing records using sidekiq. Below are my models.

#### sponsorship.rb

```
class LegiscanModel::Sponsorship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :bill, class_name: 'LegiscanModel::Bill', foreign_key: 'bill_id', inverse_of: :sponsorships

  belongs_to :sponsor, class_name: 'LegiscanModel::Politician', foreign_key: :politician_id, inverse_of: :sponsorships
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sponsor
  delegate :full_name, to: :sponsor, prefix: true, allow_nil: true

  validates :politician_id, uniqueness: { scope: :bill }

  belongs_to :sponsorship_type, class_name: 'LegiscanModel::SponsorType', foreign_key: :sponsor_type_id, inverse_of: :sponsorships
end
```

#### sponsor_type.rb

```
class LegiscanModel::SponsorType < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sponsorships, class_name: 'LegiscanModel::Sponsorship', inverse_of: :sponsor_type, dependent: :destroy
end
```

#### politician.rb

```
has_many :sponsorships, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :sponsor, class_name: 'LegiscanModel::Sponsorship'
```

#### sidekiq job(partial)

```
  def handle_sponsors(sponsors, bill_id)
    sponsors.each do |sponsor|
      LegiscanModel::Politician.find_by(people_id: sponsor['people_id']).tap do |politician|
        LegiscanModel::Sponsorship.find_or_create_by!(politician_id: politician.id, bill_id: bill_id, sponsor_order: sponsor['sponsor_order'], sponsor_type_id: sponsor['sponsor_type_id'])
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: You have `inverse_of: :sponsor_type` in `LegiscanModel::SponsorType` but in `LegiscanModel::Sponsorship` the association is called `:sponsorship_type`. So you need to either change `inverse_of: :sponsor_type` to `inverse_of: :sponsorship_type` or change `belongs_to :sponsorship_type` to `belongs_to :sponsor_type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually set your classes up properly with explicit nesting instead of using the scope resolution operator you can dramatically improve this code:

```
module LegiscanModel
  class Sponsorship < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :bill
    belongs_to :sponsor, 
       class_name: 'Politician', # specifying the module is optional
       inverse_of: :sponsorships
    belongs_to :sponsorship_type

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :sponsor
    delegate :full_name, to: :sponsor, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
    # should be the database column since its used to create a query
    validates :politician_id, uniqueness: { scope: :bill_id } 
  end
end
```

```
module LegiscanModel
  class SponsorshipType < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :sponsorships, dependent: :destroy
  end
end
```

While this might seem like a trivial stylistic choice its really not - by using `module LegiscanModel` you're reopening the module and setting the module nesting so that you can refer to constants in the same namespace.

This also avoids autoloading errors and bugs due to suprising constant lookup. `::` should only be used when refering to constants - not when defining them.

You also do not need to specify the foreign key option when it can be derived from the name of the assocation. While there is no harm in it but its extra noise. Rails can also automatically infer the inverses. You can check it with if you want to through the assocation reflexion:

```
LegiscanModel::Sponsorship.reflect_on_assocation(:sponsorship_type)
                          .inverse
```

Comment: There are some other problems here - you need to properly define what SponsorType vs SponsorshipType is in your domain. You also most likely should rewrite that task so that it doesn't do a query for every iteration and so that it actually uses assocations instead of `politician_id: politician.id` which is pretty smelly as you're leaking all the implementation details of your model into the task. Hopefully this is a nudge in the right direction.